# Программный доступ к консоли браузера

Tags: javascript, консоль, браузер, расширения

Команды `console.log()` и иже с ней, предназначенные для вывода данных в консоль и добавления всяких 'свистелок' в выводе описаны 100500 раз. Это как бы обычно.

Нашел, как можно записывать консольные выхлопы в переменные, дабы использовать эти данные потом в коде.

Интересует, есть ли еще какие-то способы взаимодействия с консолью браузера из кода страницы и/или браузерного расширения (или еще как-то)? В частности,  программно загнать в консоль текст команды/программы и выполнить их в консоли, не открывая саму консоль.

Вот например, команды `xpath ($x("//*[@class='date']/text()");)` выполняются сразу, в **js** коде нужно потанцевать с бубном немного. Возможно есть еще какие-то фичи, навскидку не помню.

Я понимаю, что такие манипуляции чреваты, ибо безопасность... Но все же. В расширениях ведь многое можно обходить.

В общем, кто что знает по данной теме, пишите. Буду рад любым подсказкам и идеям.

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете то?

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) перечислено все что можно делать с консолью.

Comment: @Bulson Вопрос не про это

Answer (score 0):

Мы можем получить доступ не только к консоли, а вообще ко всему через **DevTools**.

Но сразу предупреждаю: Это нельзя сделать скрытно, при доступе к **DevTools** отображается такая "шляпа"(там где надпись "devtools" это имя расширения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример перехвата консольных сообщений страницы и вывода в консоль расширения, та которая открывается через ссылку *Отладка страниц **фоновая страница***:

*app.js*

```js
const attached = new Set()

async function executeScript(tabId) {
  console.log(`executeScript ${tabId}`)
  await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId },
    files: ['content.js']
  })
}

void (async () => {
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, changeInfo, tabInfo) => {
    if (!/^http/.test(tabInfo?.url ?? '')) return
    console.log(`tabId:${tabId}, status:${changeInfo.status}`)
    if (changeInfo.status !== 'complete') return

    // Если обновили вкладку
    if (attached.has(tabId)) {
      await executeScript(tabId)
      return
    }

    // Присоединяем вкладку к DevTools
    chrome.debugger.attach({ tabId }, '1.3', async () => {
      console.log(`attach ${tabId}`)

      // Теперь можем прослушивать все события: Console|Network и т.п.
      chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener((debuggee, type, data) => {
        if (debuggee?.tabId !== tabId || type !== 'Console.messageAdded') return
        // Выводим сообщение консоли вкладки в devtools-консоль
        console.log(`Сообщение цели отладки tabId${tabId}:`, data)
      })

      // Активируем Console
      chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ tabId }, 'Console.enable', undefined, async (...data) => {
        // Запустим на странице тестовый скрипт
        // DevTools консоль будет отображать все сообщения страницы, в том числе и наш скрипт
        await executeScript(tabId)
        attached.add(tabId)
      })
    })

    chrome.debugger.onDetach.addListener(({ tabId }) => {
      console.log(`detached ${tabId}`)
      if (tabId) attached.delete(tabId)
    })
  })
})()
```

*content.js*

```js
console.log('Скрипт контента')
```

*manifest.json*

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "devtools",
  "description": "devtools",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Хороший человек",
  "action": {},
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "app.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "debugger"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Все три файла кидаем в один каталог и подключаем.

Comment: Ну запустил я эти файлы в виде дополнения в Хроме. Вылезла у меня шапка. Фоновой отладки я у себя не нашел (https://tvs-sm.ru/vklyuchenie-fonovoj-otladki-v-brauzerah-chrome/). Может Хром плохо знаю... 
Но это, наверное все-таки не совсем то...

Comment: @Zombotron на странице списка расширений chrome://extensions/ у каждого расширения есть ссылка `Отладка страниц _фоновая страница_`, она и открывает такой же devTools как и у страниц, но только для расширений. Эта ссылка отображается, только если включен режим разработчика.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел. То я вчера спал на ходу. )) Но таки да, не то это. Код все равно интерпретируется, как и всегда, из файла. А нужно, чтобы оно загнало его в консоль и из консоли  выполнило. $x("//*[@class='date']/text()"); по прожнему пишет  $x is not defined.